# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'assets')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm a beginner with react and I'm not exactly sure what happened all of a sudden but I was trying to build a disney+ clone and when I suddenly refreshed my page, I got all sorts of errors, the first of which said something along the lines of this:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/Users/dese.e/Web/disney-clone/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
```

At which point I added that to my webpack.config.js file and installed the necessary dependencies but now I'm getting a new set of errors which are:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'assets')
    at Compilation.createModuleAssets (/Users/dese.e/Web/disney-clone/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:4487:25)
    at /Users/dese.e/Web/disney-clone/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3052:13
    at /Users/dese.e/Web/disney-clone/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3277:6
    at Object.eachLimit (/Users/dese.e/Web/disney-clone/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3461:14)
    at runIteration (/Users/dese.e/Web/disney-clone/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3206:13)
    at Compilation._runCodeGenerationJobs (/Users/dese.e/Web/disney-clone/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3281:3)
    at /Users/dese.e/Web/disney-clone/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3037:12
    at /Users/dese.e/Web/disney-clone/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3277:6
    at /Users/dese.e/Web/disney-clone/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2818:7
    at done (/Users/dese.e/Web/disney-clone/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3522:9)
```

I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong. Could I please get some help?

These are the relevant changes to my webpack.config.js file

```
module.exports = function (webpackEnv) {
 
           
    resolve: {
 
      modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
        modules.additionalModulePaths || []
      )
      extensions: paths.moduleFileExtensions
        .map(ext => `.${ext}`)
        .filter(ext => useTypeScript || !ext.includes('ts')),
      alias: {
        // Support React Native Web
        // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
        'react-native': 'react-native-web',
        // Allows for better profiling with ReactDevTools
        ...(isEnvProductionProfile && {
          'react-dom$': 'react-dom/profiling',
          'scheduler/tracing': 'scheduler/tracing-profiling',
        }),
        ...(modules.webpackAliases || {}),
      },
      fallback: {
        "fs": false,
        "tls": false,
        "net": false,
        "path": false,
        "zlib": false,
        "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"),
        "http": false,
        "https": false,
        "stream": false,
        "crypto": false,
        "crypto-browserify": require.resolve('crypto-browserify'), //if you want to use this module also don't forget npm i crypto-browserify 
      }, 
      plugins: [
        // Prevents users from importing files from outside of src/ (or node_modules/).
        // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
        // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
        // please link the files into your node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
        // Make sure your source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
        new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [
          paths.appPackageJson,
          reactRefreshRuntimeEntry,
          reactRefreshWebpackPluginRuntimeEntry,
          babelRuntimeEntry,
          babelRuntimeEntryHelpers,
          babelRuntimeRegenerator,
        ]),
        new NodePolyfillPlugin(),
      ],
    },
```

This is where the error originates from in the compilation.js file

````
    createModuleAssets() {
        const { chunkGraph } = this;
        for (const module of this.modules) {
            if (module.buildInfo.assets) {
                const assetsInfo = module.buildInfo.assetsInfo;
                for (const assetName of Object.keys(module.buildInfo.assets)) {
                    const fileName = this.getPath(assetName, {
                        chunkGraph: this.chunkGraph,
                        module
                    });
                    for (const chunk of chunkGraph.getModuleChunksIterable(module)) {
                        chunk.auxiliaryFiles.add(fileName);
                    }
                    this.emitAsset(
                        fileName,
                        module.buildInfo.assets[assetName],
                        assetsInfo ? assetsInfo.get(assetName) : undefined
                    );
                    this.hooks.moduleAsset.call(module, fileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ```
````

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling your node_modules?

Comment: yeah i tried that but it just brought me back to my original error  `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/Users/dese.e/Web/disney-clone/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
 - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
 - install 'os-browserify'` @Jason

Comment: Hey, have you fixed it by any change? It s like 4th hour of trying for me and nothing works :(

Comment: @azrahel i ended up just deleting node modules and reinstalling and that fixed it lol